# Gradle - How to prevent tomcat-embed-el from being "taken away" from WEB-INF/lib

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle

**My objective:**
I am trying to install a Spring-boot v2.1.7.RELEASE, web service in WebSphere ND 8.5.5.15, which is working fine on localhost/tomcat.

The weird thing is a couple of times i can get the application started(after installing - i am not sure and i don't know how), but most of the time(after i retry or change a few things), i can't get the app to start in WebSphere, and i am trying to understand why.

**So right now, what i am trying to do is:**
I need to exclude the embedded tomcat from the runtime, and this can be done easily by adding this line in build.gradle:

```
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

And i understand [here](https://medium.com/@james.tran/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-2-x-apps-on-websphere-8-5-5-d0b2e257f606/) - **Step 4**, that it is also removing EL-related classes, so i brought it back:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

But right now, it is not "bringing the classes back", and i don't understand why. The tomcat-embed-el-9.0.22.jar, which contains the **javax.el.ELManager.class** is landing in **../WEB-INF/lib-provided**, after installation in WebSphere. I expected it in **../WEB-INF/lib**

I have a "solution", which is to add a this in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.24'
```

It's working, but i am doubting that this is the "correct" approach, because after i solved it, i am starting to get other hibernate issues, which is not expected, as i already did **Step 3** in the link above.

P.S The gradle version i am using is 5.5:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-bin.zip
```

I tried to use 5.6 as well, but same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core'
providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket'
```

is the correct approach.

The hibernate issue was a separate issue.